# Deploying Apps with Ionic on Android devices fails even though JDK ist installed (Ubuntu 17.04)

Tags: java, android, cordova, ubuntu, ionic-framework

I was trying to run an ionic app on my Android devices, while having installed all requirements: [Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html), [OpenJDK](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Java/Installation/OpenJDK/) (*open-source version of Oracle's Java Developer Kit*), added ANDROID_HOME and JAVA_HOME to my environment variables (*in my case ~/.profile*) and pluged my phone through USB.

**Output `java -version`:**

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_131"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
1.8.0_131-8u131-b11-2ubuntu1.17.04.3-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

**Output `javac -version`:**

```
javac 1.8.0_131
```

**Parts of `~/.profile`:**
*(my container for environment variables)*

```
# Android
export ANDROID_HOME="$HOME/Programme/Android"
export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH"
export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH"

# JAVA
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/default-java"
export PATH="$JAVA_HOME:$PATH"
```

**Output `adb devices`:**

```
List of devices attached
TA364*****  device
```

Even having set everything up, the command `ionic cordova run android` does not work and throws that error message:

> Error: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater

How to get it running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clue is to add the `/bin` folder also to your path. Type that into your `~/.profile`:

```
export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

If you have installed more than one Java version, you will have to ensure that you selected the right one corresponding to your path inside `JAVA_HOME`:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

This will give you a menu for activating that version which suits your necessities most.